# How to make section 100% size with margins?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want a border with pictures and parallax scrolling, so i added a section in the body and had the content in that. but when i make the section 100% or 100vh and add margin it goes outside the body.

Comment: Please provide your code-examples (html/css). Or better yet – add a *snippet* (CTRL + M) in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the section as full height with 20px margin. So i have added the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z2foykLj/1)

And the code here

```
<body style="margin:0;background: red; width:100%;height:100%;">

    <section style="position: absolute; display: inline-block; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; width:200px;  margin:20px; background:green;">

    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

`100vh` means that this element will be the same height device screen. For correct output you need to reset margins for this element

Comment: i want the section to be fit to the screen but with margin about 20 px

Comment: Try to use `height: calc(100vh - 20px);` and also add the `margin: 20px;`

Comment: In the upper comment i mean `margin-top` instead just `margin`. If you want margins 20px top and bottom, the height should be 20px + 20px, as you guess. Like `height: calc(100vh - 40px);` and `margin-top: 20px;`, `margin-bottom: 20px;`